# How to clone an aggregate object copies in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I want to clone a copy of aggregate object to perform 2 types of query. My example code below

```
const aggregation = db.users.aggregate().match(query);

// From there I want to split this into 2 clone object.
// Suppose there was a .clone function
const aggregation1 = aggregation.clone().count('total');
const aggregation2 = aggregation.clone().skip(skip).limit(limit);

Promise.all([aggregation1.exec(), aggregation2.exec()]);
```

How can I achieve this? I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are trying to paginate your data. You can get the paginated data and the total count of documents as explained in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60775167/11717458

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it resolves my situation, but I still think it's better to have a clone function. By the way, are there any chance to have any stages after facet? Or it must be last stage

Comment: Yes you can apply other stages after facet, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294184/facet-aggregation-in-monogdb). If my answer helped, I appreciate if you can upvote that answer. I believe it is better to get the data and the total count n one go with the help of $facet.

Comment: Sure, thank you for details explanation.

Comment: I meant upvote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770129/how-can-i-get-count-of-the-documents-and-filter-them-in-efficient-way-mongoose/60775167#60775167) in my answer:)

Comment: Ah yes, I did it :D

Comment: Thanks, as I said it is better to get the paginated data with facet in one go, there is no need to clone.

Comment: Yes, you're right. using facet will make a better query performance I believe

Answer (score 0):

I want to clone aggregation to another object so I had done as below

```
userCollection = User.aggregate();
userCollection.match({ _id: { $ne: new ObjectId("anyid")} });
//cloning to another object
let checkCount =  User.aggregate(userCollection);
let rsdata = await checkCount.count("total").exec();
//Now rsdata having total count but still you can use userCollection 
//total will be not added to userCollection pipeline
rs = userCollection.exec((err, documents) => {
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return false;   
      }
      console.log(documents);
      return true;
}
```

Then I need to count record before getting records.

In above code I have clone userCollection to checkCount object. so if you add any additional stage on checkCount , it will not impact userCollection.

I hope this will help.

Happy Coding :)